# How to find all files that are larger than 1GB on the Mac HD?

Tags: finder, command-line, unix

It seems that either one of these commands can be used:

```
sudo find / -size +1G
sudo find / -type f -size +1G
```

But when it gets to `/Volumes`, it actually look at all the back up files by Time Machine in the external hard drive. (and another hard drive for data).

I was going to cd to `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` and start the `find` there using `find .` instead of `find /`, but then I did an `ls` and there is a `Volumes` right there again.

Any option to use the Finder as well (the GUI)?

Another thing I found puzzling is that none of the manpage of `find` on Mac OS Lion or on the web mentioned the `+1G`... all they mentioned were the format `1G` for exact match.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the `-x` to avoid traversing mounted drives:

```
-x      Prevent find from descending into directories that have a device number different than that of the file from which the descent
        began.
```

You command should then be

```
$ sudo find -x / -type f -size +1G
```

Regarding the fact about the missing documentation: is not missing is just not easy to find. At the end of the `PRIMARIES` section of the man page

> All primaries which take a numeric argument allow the number to be preceded by a plus sign ("+") or a minus sign ("-").  A preceding plus sign means "more than n", a preceding minus sign means "less than n" and neither means "exactly n".

Answer (score 15):

This will probably come out with slightly different results than find but you could use Spotlight. This method is far faster than traversing every file on the drive using `find`

In a Finder window, start a Spotlight search and choose the File Size and also System files from the drop down menu. (look for the + under the search field on the top right)[image]

If you are looking to do this on the command line, you can use:

```
mdfind "kMDItemFSSize >$[1024*1024*1024]"
```

In a test on my machine, the Spotlight search didn't find a couple of large files that were in the trash or one or two system files (like sleepimage). It also treated packages (such as applications and some VM images) differently from `find`. On the upside though mdutil was nearly instant rather than taking a few minutes for the find command to trawl through my disk.

Answer (score 3):

This will find folders too which is useful when low in disk space and deciding what to delete.

du -h 2>/dev/null | grep "G\t"

Comment: ha, interesting solution... what if it is to find all files larger than 500MB?

Comment: That would be more complicated as this relies on the Gigabit output from disk usage `du`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go for a GUI tool, I use

http://www.whatsizemac.com/
or
http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidisksweeper/

Whatsize can also find duplicates an has some extra features.

Answer (score -1):

How about this command:

```
find / -type f -size +1G
```

Comment: you mean just remove the `sudo`?  But I want to find any system file that is more than 1GB too... (such as `.dmg` downloaded by the App Store)

Comment: And it doesn't solve the problem anyway because drives mounted in `/Volumes` are typically readable without sudo.